# Quicker way to specify default function arguments in php

Tags: php, function

If I had a PHP function, that had a load of default arguments, all of which were set to `false`, for example:

```
function foo($foo = false, $bar = false, $foobar = false)
{
}
```

Is there a quicker (not in execution, but coding style, practice, number of characters it takes to write the code etc.) way of doing this?

Comment: function foo($f = 0 , $b = 0 , $fb = 0) .. that is alot less characters i guess but doesnt really mean its the way to go.

Comment: For example, if I were only working with strings and not integers then "false" could be substituted with a "0" and all would be well?

Comment: @sabeen what if I were to do "$foo = 0; $foo ?: 'bar'", would "$foo" equal "bar"?

Comment: As far as i see ....... 0 == false and 1 == true .. incase you are using strings you should use quotes.

Comment: not sure what ur code is supposed to do but !$foo , $foo == 0 and $foo == false .. would act pretty much the same

Comment: `0!==false` and `1!==true`, however, `false===!1` and `true===!0`

Comment: @sabeen, write an answer detailing "$foo = 0" so I can mark you correct. You are spot on in this case.

Comment: Kudos to @mvds, loosely @sabeen's method is great but @mvds's method is more explicit. If you can be loose and are looking to reduce your code/keystrokes, @sabeen's wins in this case.

Comment: @Jonathon: If you're that sloppy, leave the default args out alltogether (and disable warnings), so they will be `null`, which also acts "pretty much the same" as `0==null` and `false==null` and `array()==null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function foo($f = 0 , $b = 0 , $fb = 0)
```

you can use 0 instead of false.

Comment: Ha, would be shorter again if no trailing space after the "0"! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
function foo($foo=!1,$bar=!1,$foobar=!1)
{
}
```

Comment: If this can't be beaten and it probably cant, kudos, I will mark it my chosen answer. Time is ticking!

Comment: I'd still go with ` = false`, though, for legibility. If you have lots of function arguments then perhaps you should reconsider your function design. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
function foo(){
    $defaults = array_merge(array_fill(0, 3, false), func_get_args());
}

foo(); //defaults is array(false, false, false);
```

i prefer passing arrays to functions/methods over the way you are doing

```
function foo($defaults = array()){
    $defaults = array_merge(array('foo' => false, 'bar' => false, 'etc' => false), (array)$defaults);
    ...
    echo $defaults['foo']; // always set
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is by no means a quicker way to code my example.